# SPO Retrieve HasUniqueRoleAssignements property using Powershell

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, properties, powershell

I am trying to retrieve `HasUniqueRoleAssignements` property for multiple SharePoint Online lists using Powershell.

I can do it for each one in SharePoint on-premises:

```
$ctx.Load($list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
```

but the same cmdlet applied for SPO tenant returns an error:

> Cannot find an overload for "Load" and the argument count: "1".
>   At C:\Users\Me\Documents\Customer.ps1:34 char:3
>   +   $ctx.Load($ll.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
>   +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

If I don't load the property, it will not be displayed as it needs to be separately requested.
I can access Fields of a list, but fields are columns and not properties.

The property can be loaded and accessed without issue using C#:

```
ctx.Load(ctx.Web.Lists, wc => wc.Include(w => w.HasUniqueRoleAssignments));
```

I also tried `$list.Retrieve()` which should retrieve the properties and IntelliSense but it didn't recognize the `HasUniqueRoleAssignments` (mind you, it doesn't even suggest `.Title`)

That begs the questions:

1. Is it possible that using CSOM I would be able to access one property with C# and not with Powershell? Where can I find a list of PS accessible properties?
2. Can I use Expression like in C# example to load the properties for all the lists or do I need to do that one by one?

Comment: I cannot answer your questions, but have you considered calling the C# from PowerShell to provide the info you need?

Comment: That's an interesting question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [ClientRuntimeContext.Load method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee536388.aspx) has the following signature:

```
public void Load<T>(
    T clientObject,
    params Expression<Func<T, Object>>[] retrievals
)
where T : ClientObject
```

### How to invoke `ClientRuntimeContext.Load<T>` method in PowerShell

`Invoke-LoadMethod` function demonstrates how to specify `retrievals` parameter for `ClientRuntimeContext.Load<T>` method in PowerShell:

```
Function Invoke-LoadMethod() {
param(
   [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject]$Object = $(throw "Please provide a Client Object"),
   [string]$PropertyName
) 
   $ctx = $Object.Context
   $load = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("Load") 
   $type = $Object.GetType()
   $clientLoad = $load.MakeGenericMethod($type) 


   $Parameter = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Parameter(($type), $type.Name)
   $Expression = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Lambda(
            [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Convert(
                [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::PropertyOrField($Parameter,$PropertyName),
                [System.Object]
            ),
            $($Parameter)
   )
   $ExpressionArray = [System.Array]::CreateInstance($Expression.GetType(), 1)
   $ExpressionArray.SetValue($Expression, 0)
   $clientLoad.Invoke($ctx,@($Object,$ExpressionArray))
}
```

Example

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve `HasUniqueRoleAssignments` property of List object:

```
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
$context.Credentials = Get-SPOCredentials -UserName $UserName -Password $Password

$list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)    
Invoke-LoadMethod -Object $list -PropertyName "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"
$context.ExecuteQuery()

Write-Host $list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments

$context.Dispose()
```

### References

- [Invoking Generic Methods on Non-Generic Classes in PowerShell](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/06/19/invoking-generic-methods-on-non-generic-classes-in-powershell/)
- [Some tips and tricks of using SharePoint Client Object Model in
  PowerShell. Part 1](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/11/19/some-tips-and-tricks-of-using-sharepoint-client-object-model-in-powershell/)

Answer (score 1):

Read this article http://jeffreypaarhuis.com/2012/06/07/scripting-sharepoint-online-with-powershell-using-client-object-model/

In one of the comments, a user has mentioned about retrieving property `HasUniqueRoleAssignments` and how he resolved it. The idea is to create a `dll` which uses `csom` to get the property. And then use it via `PowerShell`.

```
public void LoadSPWebWithBreakRoleInheritance(ClientObject objectToLoad)
{
    Web webToRetrieve = (Web) objectToLoad;
    base.Load(webToRetrieve, website => website.Title, website => website.HasUniqueRoleAssignments);
}
```

In your case, you can use similar technique to get list properties.

Comment: @VadimGremyachev Ok I have removed the statement. I will keep the answer so it will be another option for users. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Gary Lapointe](http://www.itunity.com/users/gary-lapointe) has the article [Loading Specific Values Using Lambda Expressions and the SharePoint CSOM API with Windows PowerShell](http://www.itunity.com/article/loading-specific-values-lambda-expressions-sharepoint-csom-api-windows-powershell-1249) which is providing lots of insight and also the function [Load-CSOMProperties.ps1](https://gist.github.com/glapointe/cc75574a1d4a225f401b#file-load-csomproperties-ps1) over on github

> Utility PowerShell function that facilitates the loading of specific properties of a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject object or Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObjectCollection object.

That function works fine for me, using it to retrieve HasUniqueRoleAssignements should work like this:

```
        Load-CSOMProperties -object $list -propertyNames @("HasUniqueRoleAssignments") 
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [C# code in PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts/) scripts with [Add-Type](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849914.aspx) cmdlet:

```
Add-Type -Language CSharp -ReferencedAssemblies @("$PSScriptRoot\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll", "$PSScriptRoot\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll") -TypeDefinition '
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
public static class Helper
{
    public static void LoadHasUniqueRoleAssignments(ClientContext context, SecurableObject securableObject)
    {
        context.Load(securableObject, o => o.HasUniqueRoleAssignments);
    }
}'

[Helper]::LoadHasUniqueRoleAssignments($ctx, $list)
```