# Identifying lists that have direct permissions and not inherited from the site?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, list, powershell, permissions

I have a large site I'm reviewing and I've noticed a number of lists that have direct permissions instead of inheriting from the site as we'd like.

I was wondering if there's a way I can identify all of these using powershell? I know you can do this in the interface, but I'm hoping to write something I can apply to all sites in the farm to do a full cleanup.

Comment: Are you looking for PowerShell Script for SharePoint Online? The question is tagged with both 2013 and share point-online

Comment: @NadeemYousuf 2013 style site collections, in SPO

Comment: the accepted answer is using SP Server Object Code. How did it work with SPO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following PowerShell Script to list all lists and libraries with unique permissions in a site collection:

```
Write-Host "********************************************************************"  
Write-Host "| This script will check if there are list with unique permissions |"  
Write-Host "********************************************************************"  
Write-Host  
Write-Host "Loading Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell..." -ForegroundColor Yellow  
Write-Host  

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue  

$siteURL = Read-Host "Please provide url of the SiteCollection"  
$loglocation = Read-Host "Please provide path for the log file (hit ENTER to not store output)"  
$site = Get-SPSite($siteURL)  

Write-Host  
if($loglocation -ne ""){  
    start-transcript -path $loglocation  
    Write-Host  
}  

Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------------"  

$counter = 0  
Write-Host "The following lists and libraries have unique permissions `r`n (results marked in Red might have an 64K ACL impact):" -ForegroundColor Yellow  
Write-Host  

foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {  
    foreach($list in $web.Lists) {  
        if($list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $true)  
        {  
            $counter = $counter + 1  
            if($list.ItemCount > 1500){  
                Write-Host $list.DefaultViewUrl "- ItemsCount:" $list.ItemCount -ForegroundColor Red "`r`n"  
            }else{  
                Write-Host $list.DefaultViewUrl "- ItemsCount:" $list.ItemCount "`r`n"  
            }  
        }else{  
            #Write-Host $list.DefaultViewUrl -ForegroundColor Green  "`r`n"   
        }  
    }  
}  
Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------------"  

if($counter -lt 0){  
    Write-Host $siteURL "has no lists or libraries with unique permissions!" -ForegroundColor Green  
}else{  
    Write-Host $siteURL "has $counter lists or libraries with unique permissions!"  
}  
Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------------"  

if($loglocation -ne ""){  
    Stop-Transcript  
}  
Write-Host
```

Comment: The script is using SP Server Object Model and OP was asking for a script which runs for SPO. Not sure, why OP accepted this as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Please check if below powershell script is useful to you:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

 #Get All Web Applications
$webApps = Get-SPWebApplication #"http://sharepoint.company.com"

#Write Header to CSV File
"Site/List `t Title `t URL" | out-file UniquePermissions.csv

foreach ($webApp in $webApps)
{
    foreach ($site in $webApp.Sites)
    {
       foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
        {
   if ( ($web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) -and ($web.IsRootWeb -eq $false))
   {
      $result ="Site `t $($web.Title) `t $($web.Url)"
      $result | Out-File UniquePermissions.csv -Append
      #You can get the permissions applied by: $web.permissions | format-list member, basepermissions
   }
    foreach ($list in $web.Lists)
     {
     if (($list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) -and ($list.Hidden -eq $false))
      {
        $result= "List `t $($list.Title) `t $($list.Url)"
        $result | Out-File UniquePermissions.csv -Append
      }
    }
    $web.Dispose()
  }
   $site.Dispose()
 }

}
```

Reference : http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/10/find-all-sites-and-lists-with-unique-permissions.html

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the scripts from these already existing questions which have both been answered by @Vadim Gremyachev. The script from this question gets all the site collections and the webs in them. 
[Powershell to list all sites and subsites in SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101176/powershell-to-list-all-sites-and-subsites-in-sharepoint-online)

The script in this question shows how to check whether a list has broken permissions or not:
[SPO Retrieve HasUniqueRoleAssignements property using Powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126221/spo-retrieve-hasuniqueroleassignements-property-using-powershell)